# Double clicking fire of dynamically generated web controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Dynamic button controls in a panel existing. Clicking on specific button needs to be disabled while the event is firing to prevent double click submission. Can any one suggest me some ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not what SO is for.  If you want to do something, you need to do the research to find out how and then do it.  If it doesn;t work as expected, THEN you would post a question here, telling us what you're trying to achieve, showing us how your trying to achieve it and telling us what happens when you try and how that differs from your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

To Use in HTML:

```
<asp:LinkButton Style="color: red; font-family: verdana" runat="server" ID="LinkEliminar">Eliminar</asp:LinkButton>
```

To Use in ASPX

```
Protected Sub LinkEliminar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkEliminar.Click
        Label16.Text = "¿Eliminar Requisición No." & Label14.Text & "?.-"
        eliminar.Visible = True
End Sub
```